# String pointer syntax, is this correct?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, syntax, visual-c++-2008

I'm coming from a C# background and my C++ is very rusty so please bear with me.

The following function definition accepts pointers (LPTSTR) to strings representing an input filename (szIn) and output filename (szOut). Here is the function prototype:

```
ConvertFile(LPTSTR szIn, LPTSTR szOut);
```

Currently the function is executed from within some UI code, here's an example of how the output filename is obtained from the pointer `szOutput`:

```
TCHAR szOutput[255];    // output filename

if (g_szFilename[0] != 0)
{
    SetDlgItemText(hMainDlg, IDC_EDIT_INPUT, g_szFilename);
    _tcscpy(szOutput, g_szFilename);
    TCHAR * szExt = _tcsrchr(szOutput, '.');
    if (szExt != NULL) *szExt = 0;
    _tcscat(szOutput, _T(".png"));
}
```

I want to do something along these lines:

```
TCHAR inputFilename[256];
TCHAR outputFilename[256];

inputFilename += "somefile.txt";
outputFilename += "someotherfile.txt";

char *inputPtr;
char *outputPtr;

inputPtr = inputFilename;
outputPtr = outputFilename;

ConvertFile(inputPtr, outputPtr);
```

Is this the correct syntax for Microsoft's flavor of C++ in Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages, and do this *very* differently. Which language are you using?

Comment: @BoPersson I edited to clarify I'm using C++ here, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: "Microsoft's flavor of C++ in Visual Studio 2008" is just C++ -- why would it be different in any fashion (modulo compiler bugs)? Note that VC++ also compiles a language called C++/CLI, maybe that's what you're referring to? If so, the code you've shown is far from idiomatic.

Comment: If it were C++/CLI, there wouldn't be LPTSTRs and TCHARs, would there?   It'd just be `System::String^` and `char`.

Comment: -1 for a yes-no question that the compiler could have told you the answer to. If you doubt whether the compiler's answer is correct, then you need to mention that detail.

Comment: @cHao : C++/CLI is allowed to use native types/functions (assuming you're not compiling with `/clr:safe`), it's just more idiomatic to use `System::String^` etc. (and C#'s `char` is `wchar_t` in C++ and C++/CLI).

Answer (score 4):

Nope.  C++ strings can do what you're trying to do:

```
// Since we don't know whether to use string or wstring, we're stuck
// with basic_string<TCHAR>
std::basic_string<TCHAR> inputFilename, outputFilename;

// Note the TEXT macro...it makes sure your chars are TCHARs
inputFilename += TEXT("somefile.txt");
outputFilename += TEXT("someotherfile.txt");

// basic_string::c_str() returns you a pointer suitable for C stuff
// (since this is a string of TCHARs, we'll get a const TCHAR* back)
ConvertFile(inputFilename.c_str(), outputFilename.c_str());
```

C char arrays can't be concatenated like that.  You'd have to use `_tcscat` or other similar functions.

Comment: Or you could use `std::wstring` which is also defined as `std::basic_string<wchar_t>` ;)

Comment: @LihO: The type that `TCHAR` aliases is determined by whether you're compiling for ANSI or Unicode.  The second you use `std::wstring`, you might as well just toss all the `TCHAR`s and `TEXT("whatever")` macros out the window as well, and just say `wchar_t` and `L"whatever"` respectively -- cause you've just sacrificed compatibility with 8-bit chars.

Comment: Yeah, Multi-Byte Character Set... `TCHAR` defined as a `char`... 16-bit chars by default are much better

Answer (score 1):

This is illegal:

```
inputFilename += "somefile.txt";
outputFilename += "someotherfile.txt";
```

You can use `_tcscpy()` to copy strings:

```
TCHAR inputFilename[256]  = { 0 }; /* FYI, the '= { 0 }' initialises the array.*/
TCHAR outputFilename[256] = { 0 };

_tcscpy(inputFilename, "somefile.txt");
```

and use `_tcscat()` to concatenate:

```
_tcscat(inputFilename, "another-bit.txt");
```

You can then pass to `ConvertFile()`:

```
ConvertFile(inputFilename, outputFilename);
```

there is no need to create another pointer to these variables (as the arrays will decay to pointers).

EDIT:

After change in language you can make use of `std::basic_string`:

```
std::basic_string<TCHAR> inputFilename(TEXT("somefile.txt"));
std::basic_string<TCHAR> outputFilename(TEXT("someotherfile.txt"));
```

And you can perform concatenation as you initially wanted:

```
inputFilename += TEXT("a-bit-more");
```

And use `c_str()` method to access the internal character array to pass to `ConvertFile()`:

```
ConvertFile(inputFilename.c_str(), outputFilename.c_str());
```

Note that `c_str()` returns a `const`, change `ConvertFile()` to (*I making an assumption that `ConvertFile()` does not change the buffers passed in*):

```
ConvertFile(LPCTSTR szIn, LPCTSTR, szOut);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot concatenate a string like that.  You are trying to append a `const char[]` onto the end of another array... which won't even compile.  You need to use [_tcscat()](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/b33f6a65-8420-4c8e-a9ff-9c347a6a1b7a) or (better yet as you have added the C++ tag), `std::basic_string<TCHAR>`.

Comment: Interesting... was this a revenge downvote or is something actually wrong here?

Comment: @LihO: I answered first (check the time), and mine includes the correct way to solve the problem.

Comment: @LihO: Just responding to your comment.  I upvote helpful answers, downvote incorrect or unhelpful answers.  That's all.

Comment: @LihO: I appreciate that, but 1) I did not downvote for "no reason", I downvoted because your answer was not useful, and 2) I did not post "almost the same answer", I posted an answer that includes a solution.  I never meant to start a fight here, I'm not sure why you are so "disgusted".

Comment: @LihO: I'll remove my downvote if you include a solution, but as it stands it's just not helpful.  Like I said, this isn't personal, I have no problem upvoting a good answer even if I responded to the same thread.

Comment: @LihO: Except yours was not useful at all.  Telling the OP "yeah, you're right, that won't work" doesn't set them down the right path.  Obviously they are asking how it should be done.

Comment: @LihO: I edited it, but sometimes you need to look past the obvious to give a good answer to a beginner.

Comment: Lesson learned. I apologize for overreacting. By the way it wouldn't be a bad idea to clean up few comments here.

Comment: @LihO: Haha, probably not a bad idea, they come off as schizophrenic at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. The TCHAR arrays should already decay into TCHAR pointers, which is what LPTSTR is (a `TCHAR*`). So, you shouldn't be using `char*` pointers, unless the function is declared to accept LPCSTR. Long story short, you can use `inputFilename` and `outputFilename` directly.

Aside from that minor matter, the real issue is that `+=` won't work (it will attempt to do pointer arithmetic, if anything, which is not at all what you want). Instead, use `_tcscat()`:

```
_tcscat(inputFilename, TEXT("somefile.txt"));
// ...
```

As usual, beware the buffer overflow vulnerabilities that come with working with low-level character arrays this way...

One more thing: You never initialize `inputFilename` and `outputFilename` -- They'll need to be initialized to some string before you can concatenate to them.

Comment: The original question has been updated to refer to C++; this answer was meant for C. Please do not do things this way if you're using C++.